# Heroku Django install pillow

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip, python-imaging-library

I have a problem with Heroku and Pillow
i developed a apps with django and i have a columns with ImageField
During the deploiement in heroku, i have a error message for pillow install with pip.

error message:

```
product.Profile.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

Model django:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

Do you have a solution to my problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you added `Pillow` in your `requirements.txt`?

`Pillow` is required for ImageField.

If you had not added `Pillow` in `requirements.txt` add this line:

```
Pillow
```

Comment: Yes it is in the requierements, I even tried to install it manually with pip install in the Heroku commands

When I do the installation with the heroku commands, it tells me that the installation was done. But if I want to uninstall it after it tells me that it is not installed ....

Comment: Did you include `PIL` too? [Pillow Doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) says, **Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.** Also is it work in the local environment?

Comment: Pil is not installed. 
It works well locally

Comment: I am not sure why it's happening. Can you share the Heroku installation log and version of Python?

Comment: Problem solved, my requirements file was not updating .... Thank you for your help